# Order by the greatest value of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I don't really know if the title reflects my concern, so if you suggest a better one, go ahead.

I have a table in SQL that has two columns which represent price values :

```
rent_cost
sale_cost
```

I need to select all them regardless if they are being rent or sold. That part is ok, but then I need to order all of them by price (regardless if it's rent or sale). The thing is sometimes a row might or not might have one of the values, so I really can't crack this one.

I need to order them as if price was only one value and not two.

Example

```
{
 id:1,
 rent_value: 3000,
 sale_value: null
},
{
 id:2,
 rent_value: 2200,
 sale_value:4500
},
{
 id:3,
 rent_value: null,
 sale_value: 3300
},
```

If I select all of them by price value in descending order, I should get in return `[2,3,1]`

PD: I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `greatest()`, but you have to be careful about `NULL` values:

```
order by greatest(coalesce(rent_value, 0), coalesce(sale_value, 0)) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your solution seems like it should work, but it does not.
For example, running that in this sample DB: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab1c1e/1/0

I should get [4,1,2,3] which is the correct descending order of the highest value (regardless rent or sale).

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Your solution is correct. It is just because the value columns were defined as varchar, it was behaving in a weird way. Changing them to int work as expected.